# This image lacks the attributes necessary for tracking

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

I am trying to create a scene inside the Reality Composer to track images.

So I added a cube, an image, and I see this error message

> This image lacks the attributes necessary for tracking.

[image]

I have tried with different images, same message.

After reading the extensive documentation Apple wrote about the theme (zero lines), I ask you guys what what kind of attributes should the be present on tracking image...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, there's no official documentation on that topic. But you can get to the bottom of the truth experimentally. A reference picture you've imported for image tracking has repetitive pattern. If you change it for a proper image you'll never receive such a message again.

Here are some tips for correct reference image attributes:

- Well-discernable pattern
- No repetitive pattern (like yours, or stripes, or polka dot)
- High-contrast edges of silhouettes on a picture
- High-contrast colours (RGB image mustn't be a solid grey if you convert it into B&W)
- Moderate size (400 x 400 pix is quite enough)
- No white-sheet-image or gradient-only-image
- RGB linear color space
- 72 pixels per inch
- No high compression for JPG

Comment: Thanks, I will try that but who writes documentations for Apple has to be fired. I am undecided if Apple hates or despises developers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to make my image higher quality and I didn’t get that message at all after that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).